# Is there an exists method for any attribute in the index

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Is there an exists method for any attribute in the index, we have a method to check if it exists by ID. How do we build an abstraction to check if an entity exists using a different attribute.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repository/support/SimpleElasticsearchRepository.html#existsById-ID-

Comment: What's the difference with a term (exact match) query on a given field of the document?

Comment: Ping @Rpj, any input?

Answer (score 2):

Consider you have a class named Student as your domain class and you define your repository as follows:

```
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, String> {
}
```

To enrich `StudentRepository` with custom functionality, you must first define a fragment interface and an implementation for the custom functionality (the implementation class name must be exactly the same as the interface repository name and terminated by "Impl"), as follows:

```
public interface CustomizedStudentRepository {
  boolean existsByField(String key, Object value);
}
```

Then, you must provide an implementation for your custom repository:

```
public class CustomizedStudentRepositoryImpl {
  
  @Autowired
  private final RestHighLevelClient client;

  boolean existsByField(String key, Object value) {
      SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
      searchSourceBuilder
          .query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(key, value));
      SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest(indexName);
      request.source(searchSourceBuilder);
      try {
        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(request, 
            RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        long totalHits = searchResponse.getHits().getTotalHits().value;
        return totalHits > 0;
     } catch(IOException ioException) {
         // log exception
     }
     return false;
  }
}
```

And then refactoring your `StudentRepository` as follows:

```
interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, String>, CustomizedStudentRepository {
}
```

More [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.1.3/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations).